# How to ask user for permission to play sound in Chrome browser

Tags: angular, google-chrome

```js
var sound = new Howl({
            src: [this.config['Audio'].English],
            preload: true,
            sprite: this.AudioSpriteEn,
            autoplay: true,
            html5: true,
            muted: false,           
        });    
sound.play();
```

I want to autoplay sound `onload` in my Angular website but Chrome's autoplay policy is preventing the sound from playing.

Comment: You just need user interaction

Comment: How can i manage this without any button click?

Comment: please include some code to show your efforts

Comment: @AmitGautam You don't

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: unfortunately browsers are trying to outsmart developers and they can't imagine a scenario where a user would want to hear a sound without first clicking on a button. It's very difficult to create a browser based game because you are constantly fighting with browser's restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the browser expects the user does the first interaction with your website to then trigger a sound. Are you trying to play after user clicks something or are you playing automatically after the website load?

Accordding to Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

> From the user's perspective, a web page or app that spontaneously starts making noise without warning can be jarring, inconvenient, or off-putting. Because of that, browsers generally only allow autoplay to occur successfully under specific circumstances.

And this is what chrome says about: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

> Muted autoplay is always allowed. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
> -User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).   -On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed,
> meaning the user has previously played video with sound.   -The user
> has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA
> on desktop. Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their
> iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

In fact you don't need the user to click specifically in a big red button with the words "MAKE NOISE", instead, clicking on any other element in your website (list, divs, images, sliders...) count as "the user interaction", that brings you a other possibilities. I.E: If you show a big Cookies advertisement banner, you can start playing the audio after the user closes that banner.

BYPASS FIRST USER INTERACTION RULE:

**Method 1:**
Give your website PWA capabilities and requesting the user to install your PWA, after that you will be able to play sound without user first interaction. **NOTE:** this is according to chrome documentation, can break on other browsers.
[https://web.dev/add-manifest/#:~:text=The%20web%20app%20manifest%20is,when%20the%20app%20is%20launched.](https://web.dev/add-manifest/#:%7E:text=The%20web%20app%20manifest%20is,when%20the%20app%20is%20launched.)

**Method 2:**

Listen whichever is the first user click inside your website body, and plays the sound. Try running the snippet and then clicking the resulting body

```js
const ks = new Audio('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3')
let userinteraction = 0
document.addEventListener('click',()=>{
 if(userinteraction) return;
 userinteraction++;
 ks.play()
})
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h1>
```

Comment: Is there any way to bypass chrome autoplay policy or ask user to give sound permission?

Comment: @AmitGautam have you ever found any solution? to ask the user for sound permission or any other alternative. I'm also stuck on the same issue.

Comment: @David any solution? how to ask the user for sound permission?

Answer (score 0):

basically .play() returns a promise object....

so I created an interval to constantly check if the promise is resolved(which gets resolved after the user interaction)

and then i simply play the audio and clear the interval

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
<script>
  var audio = new Audio('notification_sound.mp3');
  var UserInteracted = setInterval(()=>{
    audio.play()
    .then(()=>{
      clearInterval(UserInteracted);
    })
    .catch(()=>{
      console.log("waiting for user interaction to play first notification")
    });     
  },1000)
</script>
</html>
```